# Windows Service- Can it run two separate tasks scheduled at different intervals

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services

I have written a Windows Service which triggers email ONCE in a WEEK at specific time. The service runs perfectly fine. Code is shown below:

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.Log("Simple Service Started");
        this.ScheduleService();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.Log("Simple Service Stopped");
        this.Schedular.Dispose();
    }

    private Timer Schedular;

    public void ScheduleService()
    {
        try
        {
            Schedular = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallback));
            // Code that schedules the Callback
        }
     }

    private void SchedularCallback(object e)
    {
        try
        {
                  // Scheduled Job code
         }
     }
```

Now I have another similar requirement where I have to trigger another email, but its schedule has to be ONCE in 2 WEEKS. Is there a way this job can be accommodated in the same service, or I have to write another service?

Comment: If the service is just idly waiting for the right time of day/week, etc to do things but is otherwise not achieving anything useful, I'd suggest using a windows scheduled task instead (or any other piece of scheduling software), rather than implementing it as a custom service.

Answer (score 3):

I once did a similar design in one of my projects.
Try having a base abstract "ScheduledTask" class that defines your timing behavior, and have it used by inherited tasks classes.

Here is what I did for timers, I think there's only little work to change it to a Scheduler.

```
internal abstract class TaskBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Task timer
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set refresh time
    /// </summary>
    protected int TimeRefreshSec { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loop of timePassed
    /// </summary>
    protected int TimePassed { get; private set; }

    protected TaskBase(double refreshInterval)
    {
        TimeRefreshSec = (int) refreshInterval / 1000;
        TimePassed = 0;

        _timer = new Timer(refreshInterval) { AutoReset = true };
        _timer.Elapsed += Tick;
    }

    private void Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimePassed += TimeRefreshSec;

        Tick();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        ResetTimer();

        // Run the task once when starting instead of waiting for a full interval.
        Tick();
        OnStart();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_timer.Enabled)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            OnStop();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void ResetTimer()
    {
        TimePassed = 0;
        if (_timer.Enabled) _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement here a specific behavior when task is stopped.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void OnStop();

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement here a specific behavior when task is started.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void OnStart();

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is executed each time the task's timer has reached the interval specified in the constructor.
    /// Time counters are automatically updated.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void Tick();
}
```

and for the service :

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly List<TaskBase> _tasks; 

    public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add in this list the tasks to run periodically.
        // Tasks frequencies are set in the corresponding classes.
        _tasks = new List<TaskBase>
        {
            new InheritingTask(),
            new OherInheritingTask()
        };
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            _tasks.ForEach(t => t.Start());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _tasks.ForEach(t => t.Stop());
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The code for a class inheriting TaskBase:

```
class InheritingTask: TaskBase
{
    public InheritingTask()
        : base(Settings.Default.InheritingTaskInterval) // In milliseconds
    {
        //TODO: Custom initialization here
    }

    protected override void Tick()
    {
        //TODO: Task logic here
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    { }

    protected override void OnStop()
    { }

    protected override void ResetTimer()
    {
        //TODO: Custom reset logic here
        base.ResetTimer();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising: Can you please share implementation of either Inheriting Class, or, OtherInheriting Class. that would be of great help

Comment: I added it in my answer, but VS likely would've told you how to implement it.

Comment: Ok. So How would I specify the interval separately for both Classes(say 1 week and 2 week)..Will it be in constructor definition ? like.....public InheritingTask() : base(604800000) 
    {
        //TODO: Custom initialization here
    }
Note: 604800000  is millisecond equivalent for 1 Week

Comment: Exactly! Thus, your tasks have the same timing behavior, but different intervals.

Comment: Is there a way I can specify if I want weekly mail at specific time: say EVERY MONDAY, 6PM

Comment: This is out of the scope of the original question, but I guess overriding a constructor in TaskBase for it to take a DayOfWeek and a Time, then calculating the remaining time with a scheduler in the constructor… Sorry, I don't have much time left to study the matter, but it's definitely feasible.

Comment: I am little perplexed, e.g. For 1 week starting say Monday,  I have set the refreshInterval value to 7 days and TimePassed value in the Constructor to 2 days (in case today is Saturday) and recalculating it later to 0 every time. Still it is not working as expected

Answer (score 2):

You could easily make a 2nd `Schedular` that is started in `ScheduleService` that is set to go off in two weeks however a `Timer` that fires once a week or two is a horrible way to do this, if the computer reboots you loose your timer and the email you where waiting on will not get sent.

You need a database of some kind to store when the next event should fire to survive restarts of your program, use a library that stores and does the scheduling for you like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

Comment: I don't think it's a horrible way to do this, since he said it has to be done at a specific time. If the time is specified (as in `DateTime`) and saved somewhere, you'll only need to calculate the interval and set it every time the service starts. So if the PC should crash and reboot, the timer is set again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this using multithreading, for example via [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Backgroundworkers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx). With this you can start each timer on a different thread which executes your operation when the timer ticks. It would also be advisable to separate timer and execution on different threads - for example Backgroundworkers for Timer 1 and 2 and Backgroundworkers for Execution 1 and 2.

Comment: Can you please help with some sample code to write 2 schedules using Tasks and Background workers